# Showing a sequence defined recursively is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, induction

Given the recursively defined sequence

$$ a_1 = 0, a_{n+1} = \frac 1{2+a^n} $$

Show it converges. I'm working with Cauchy sequences, and proved in a previous question that any sequence of real numbers $(a_n)$ satisfying:

$$|a_n - a_{n+1}| \leq \frac1{2^n} $$

is convergent (by showing $(a_n)$ was Cauchy), and was told that it may be helpful to use induction to prove that the above recursive sequence satisfies the inequality and is therefore convergent.

***Work***:

*Base Case:* When $n = 1 , a_1 = 0, a_2 = \frac12,$ so $$ \left|0-\frac12\right| \leq \frac1{2^{1}}$$ and the base case checks out

*Inductive Step:* Want to show $$|a_{n+1} - a_{n+2}| \leq \frac1{2^{n+1}} $$

So $$\left|\frac1{2+a_n} - \frac1{2+a_{n+1}}\right| \leq \frac1{2^{n+1}}$$

And I'm not sure where to proceed from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: How would you subtract the fractions $$\frac1{2+a_n} - \frac1{2+a_{n+1}}?$$

Comment: What happens when you write the difference as one fraction?

Comment: The recurrence is supposed to be $a_{n+1}=\frac1{2+a_n}$, right?

Comment: Have you been asked to prove it using a specific way?

Comment: @science no, just prove it's convergent, but was given the hint of using induction to prove that the inequality holds in this case.

Also, induction's a weak point for me as I don't have much experience in it until recently. After obtaining a common denominator under the absolute value I'm not sure how to proceed to prove what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing as Thomas Andrews suggested,
$a_{n+1}-a_{n+2}
=\frac1{2+a_n}-\frac1{2+a_{n+1}}
=\frac{(2+a_{n+1})-(2+a_n)}{(2+a_n)(2+a_{n+1})}
=\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{(2+a_n)(2+a_{n+1})}
$
so
$|a_{n+1}-a_{n+2}|
=\big|\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{(2+a_n)(2+a_{n+1})}\big|
<|\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{4}|
$.

From this,
$|a_{n+k}-a_{n+k+1}|
<|\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{4^k}|
$.
Putting
$n = 0$,
$|a_{k}-a_{k+1}|
<|\frac{a_{1}-a_0}{4^k}|
$
which is more than enough
to get convergence.

It is interesting
that this shows that
the convergence is at least
$\frac1{4^k}$,
not just
$\frac1{2^k}$.

To find the limit:
$|a_{n+1}-a_{n}|
=|a_n-\frac1{2+a_n}|
=|\frac{a_n(2+a_n)-1}{2+a_n}|
=|\frac{a^2_n+2a_n-1}{2+a_n}|
=|\frac{(a_n+1)^2-2}{2+a_n}|
$.

Since $a_n$ converges,
$(a_n+1)^2-2
\to 0
$
or
$a_n \to \sqrt{2}-1$.

To find the true rate of convergence,
since
$a_n \to \sqrt{2}-1$,
$|a_{n+1}-a_{n+2}|
=\big|\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{(2+a_n)(2+a_{n+1})}\big|
\approx \big|\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{(2+\sqrt{2}-1)(2+\sqrt{2}-1)}\big| 
= \big|\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{(\sqrt{2}+1)^2)}\big| 
= \big|\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{3+\sqrt{2}}\big| 
$,
so the convergence
is like
$\frac1{(3+\sqrt{2})^k}
$.

Answer (score -1):

To prove the sequence is convergent using the inequality

$$ |a_{n+1}-a_n| < \frac{1}{2^n} $$

you need the fact which states that "if $\sum_{n} |a_{n+1}-a_n|< \infty $ then the sequence $a_n$ is Cauchy" which implies the sequence is convergent.

Comment: I'm not sure I've gotten that far yet, I haven't seen that sum before. I've only recently been introduced to Cauchy sequences